# Import error when calling method from same module in timeit()

Tags: python, timeit

I want to measure the execution time of the Python method *sayHello()* using the method *getExecutionTime()*. They are both in a module and the *getExecutionTime()*-method should be callable from outside.

The code looks like this:

```
def getExecutionTime():
    t = timeit.Timer("sayHello", "from __main__ import sayHello")
    return t.timeit(2)

def sayHello():
    print("Hello")
```

I keep getting an ImportError saying: "Cannot import name sayHello in File ..."

I added the scope argument (`"from __main__ import sayHello"`) to the Timer constructor to make the *sayHello()* method available within the timeit scope.

**Note:** I don't want to call getExecutionTime() in the main part of this method, I want to that method from somewhere else.

Can anyone help?
Thanks.

Comment: `sayHello` and `getExecutionTime` are functions or methods? If they are methods of a class you should do this `timeit.timeit(instance.sayHello)` to get the execution time of the `sayHello`method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a file that is literally this:

```
import timeit

def getExecutionTime():
    t = timeit.Timer("sayHello()", "from __main__ import sayHello")
    return t.timeit(2)

def sayHello():
    print("Hello")

print(getExecutionTime())
```

When run, it prints `Hello` twice and then the execution time. (Also note that it's `sayHello()` rather than `sayHello` in the `Timer` set up).

Are you running this from within an IDE? From the command line & IDLE it works for me, under both Python 2.7 & 3.2.

Answer (score -2):

the code, as it is written, and having imported timeit, works fine for me as well, no ImportError...